# Bootstrap flex does not show all svg on print

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, web

I have this html code with  angular dynamically rendered svg

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="hdn">
        <h2>Barcode Generator</h2>
        <button (click)="createBarcode()">Load Barcode</button>
        <!-- <button (click)="onPrint()">Print</button> -->
    </div>
    <div id="toPrint" class="d-flex align-content-start flex-wrap">
        <div class="p-4 text-center" *ngFor="let t of Data">
            <svg [attr.id]="'b-'+t.barcode"></svg><br>
            <span>{{t.name}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

which would give me this output on browser.

[image: First page]

[image: last page]

my problem is : as I print preview this in browser it only gives me 10 barcodes printed but I have 78 barcodes rendered

[image: print scale:100%]

and tried lower scale

[image: print lower scale]

where could be the problem on my codes

i have this code in style.css for print

```
@media print {
body * {
  visibility:hidden;
}
#toPrint * {
  visibility:visible;
}
#toPrint {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}
```

}

thank you so much in advance :)

Comment: Barcode under sub title set minimum width

Comment: tried but gives me 12 barcodes with smaller width

Comment: tried scale: 30% and give me full output

Comment: can you set width and height for title